# pytest fixture yield generator (Get infinite set of predictable values)

Tags: pytest

I want to test a table with `created_at` field (`datetime` type).
(I'm doing sort on this field in the code).
For this I want to create some infinite set (generator) of predictable `datetime` values.
The "infinite" is because I don't to modify a set every time that I will have changes in count of table records (or any another table with `created_at` field).

So I did 2 fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def frozen_datetime_gen(utc_now_):
    while True:
        next_datetime = utc_now_ + datetime.timedelta(days=365)
        yield next_datetime


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def utc_now():
    yield datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

But getting the error:
`fixture function has more than one 'yield':`

I'm understanding the problem and the error but don't understand what I should do to solve it.
Maybe I choose wrong strategy and I should renounce from the predictable datetimes set?

P.S. I'm novice in tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pytest fixtures are already generators. In order to use a generator-within-generator with pytest.fixture, you need to define a `generator` function within your fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def frozen_datetime_gen(utc_now_):
    def generator():
        while True:
            next_datetime = utc_now_ + datetime.timedelta(days=365)
            yield next_datetime
    return generator

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def utc_now():
    def generator():
        yield datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    return generator
```